# Conditional Branching in Java

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I'd like to know which of these you think is a better design. Supposing we have

```
/*
* Created 21 Feb 2014
*/


import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;

/**
*
* @author me
*/

enum EventType{
    TRADE, RISK, SHIPPING, MARGIN, STOP_LOSS, TAKE_PROFIT
}

interface Event{
    EventType getType();
    Properties getProperties();
}


class ShippingEvent implements Event{
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY1 = "property_ke1";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY2 = "property_ke2";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY3 = "property_ke3";

    @Override
    public EventType getType() {
        return EventType.SHIPPING;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}


class TradeEvent implements Event{
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY1 = "property_ke1";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY2 = "property_ke2";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY3 = "property_ke3";

    @Override
    public EventType getType() {
        return EventType.TRADE;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}

class RiskEvent implements Event{
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY1 = "property_ke1";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY2 = "property_ke2";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY3 = "property_ke3";

    @Override
    public EventType getType() {
        return EventType.RISK;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}

class MarginEvent implements Event{
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY1 = "property_ke1";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY2 = "property_ke2";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY3 = "property_ke3";

    @Override
    public EventType getType() {
        return EventType.MARGIN;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}

class StopLossEvent implements Event{
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY1 = "property_ke1";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY2 = "property_ke2";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY3 = "property_ke3";

    @Override
    public EventType getType() {
        return EventType.STOP_LOSS;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}

class TakeProfiEvent implements Event{
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY1 = "property_ke1";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY2 = "property_ke2";
    public final static String PROPERTY_KEY3 = "property_ke3";

    @Override
    public EventType getType() {
        return EventType.TAKE_PROFIT;
    }

    @Override
    public Properties getProperties() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }
}

public class InstanceOfTest {

    private static void testIfBranch(final Event event){
        if (event instanceof TakeProfiEvent){
            System.out.println("TakeProfiEvent");
        }else if (event instanceof StopLossEvent){
            System.out.println("StopLossEvent");
        }else if (event instanceof MarginEvent){
            System.out.println("MarginEvent");
        }else if (event instanceof RiskEvent){
            System.out.println("RiskEvent");
        }else if (event instanceof TradeEvent){
            System.out.println("TradeEvent");
        }else if (event instanceof ShippingEvent){
            System.out.println("ShippingEvent");
        }
    }




    private static void testSwitchBranch(final Event event){

        switch(event.getType()){
            case TRADE:
                System.out.println("TradeEvent");
                break;
            case RISK:
                System.out.println("RiskEvent");
                break;
            case SHIPPING:
                System.out.println("ShippingEvent");
                break;
            case MARGIN:
                System.out.println("MarginEvent");
                break;
            case STOP_LOSS:
                System.out.println("StopLossEvent");
                break;
            case TAKE_PROFIT:
                System.out.println("TakeProfiEvent");    
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Event[] events = new Event[] {
            new TakeProfiEvent(),
            new StopLossEvent(),
            new MarginEvent(),
            new RiskEvent(),
            new TradeEvent(),
            new ShippingEvent()
        };


        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        for(int idx=0; idx<10000000; ++idx){
            int jdx = random.nextInt(events.length-1);
            //testIfBranch(events[jdx]);
            testSwitchBranch(events[jdx]);
        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start));
    }

}
```

The test I've carried out shows that the switch statement performs better for all test cases as expected according to [Compiling switch in the JVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html#jvms-3.10). Also I'm inclined to not to use the  `instanceof` operator because I find that in this case it makes extending the software difficult. For example, I using the `getType()` methodology, I can easily use IoC or DI. Also I think that using the `instanceof` operator creates a clear dependency on a class definition. I'd like to hear your thoughts on this especially in terms of software engineering - Pitfalls and/or best practice.

Example results:

```
Switch Branch: 304916ms
If Branch: 307924ms
```

Comment: The performance difference between the two is negligible; choose the one that will be easier to comprehend and manage (which looks like the `switch` variant anyway).

Comment: An enum switch usually compiles down to an *O(1)* `tableswitch`, unless you only have cases for a subset of enum values with sparse ordinals, in which case you might get an *O(log n)* `lookupswitch` (but most compilers will guarantee a `tableswitch`).  Either way, it will be better than an *O(n)* straight chain of `if/else if` statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best design is with no doubt the switch one. For best practices, see
http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=31

Comment: This article does not propose the `switch` solution (instead, it proposes polymorphism, as I mentioned in http://stackoverflow.com/a/21936703 )

Comment: true, I didn't interpret the aim of the code, just the comparison between the two methods. To be a bit more thorough, I suggest some reading in the excellent java [tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html) event if the event part is centered on Swing.
I would also suggest to check the [EventObject](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EventObject.html).
Hope I was of some help!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see from the stripped example, both approaches are not really extensible and easily maintainable in terms of software engineering.

The important question is: What are you doing with these events (and their types) in your *real* application? That is: Is it really *necessary* to query the type?

The general pattern that you should at least *consider* in this case is to hide the type queries by some sort of polymorphism. To point it out in an overly suggestive form:

```
interface Event{
    void performAction();
    Properties getProperties();
}

class ShippingEvent implements Event{
    @Override
    public void performAction() {
        // Whatever you would otherwise do based on the event type:
        System.out.println("ShippingEvent");
    }
    ....
}


private static void testPolymorphism(final Event event){ 
    event.performAction(); // That's it. No type queries here.
}
```

But whether (and how) this is applicable in your case is hard to tell from the posted code...

Comment: couldn't agree with you more.

Answer (score 0):

The performance argument in this case does not have a lot to do with if versus switch since you are doing different things in them. Your if is testing if a class is of a certain type, while your switch is checking enum equality.

Furthermore, in terms of design you give very little information so it's hard to give any judgement on what might be better. A good first step for making this discussion better, would be if you provided some information as to why you are making these conditional statements, and what you expect to do on each branch.

In terms of best practices, you want to avoid such long if/else constructs or switch statements and depending on your circumstances adopt a solution such as polymorphism.